# Brew install watchman on mac does run the service

Tags: django, watchman

I am on Mac ventura 13.0.1 (22A400)

I am trying to install watchman however it is not getting installed as a service that can be run in service/daemon mode:

```
$ brew install watchman
==> Downloading https://formulae.brew.sh/api/cask.json

Warning: watchman 2023.02.13.00 is already installed and up-to-date.
To reinstall 2023.02.13.00, run:
  brew reinstall watchman
```

However, it says that it cannot be run and loadable:

```
$ brew services info watchman
watchman (homebrew.mxcl.watchman)
Running: ✘
Loaded: ✘
Schedulable: ✘
```

Brew services list:

```
$ brew services list

Name      Status  User     File
memcached started xxx ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.memcached.plist
rabbitmq  started xxx ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.rabbitmq.plist
redis     none
stunnel   none
```

However I can use watchman in command line mode, but other programs that need to find watchman can't use it